# how to make a select box which has a particular value preselected using grails2.0

Tags: drop-down-menu, grails-2.0

I have the following line in my gsp

```
<g:select name="platform" from="['Date','Time','Place','Calendar']"/>
```

I want the Time option to be automatically selected while loading the page.

```
<select>
  <option value="Date">Date</option>
  <option value="Time" selected="selected">Time</option>
  <option value="Place">Place</option>
  <option value="Calendar">Calendar</option>
</select>
```

This is what i need when my gsp page got rendered into html.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting the g:select value

```
<g:select name="platform" from="['Date','Time','Place','Calendar']" value="'Time'"/>
```

but it would be better to bind it to an model.